# RecyclerView not updating with list from XmlPullParse

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I'm attempting to write an app for playing podcasts from an RSS feed, mostly to challenge myself to see if I can pull it off, but I've ran into some trouble with populating the RecyclerViewer.  I've been able to successfully parse the RSS feed and store it in a MutableList, using Log statements I can verify its working(in the background thread at least), but when I try to update the adapter nothing seems to happen.

I've been using The BigNerdRanch android book as my introduction to android, and I've looked at several examples for working with RecyclerViewers, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I can't help but wonder if I need to use a handler to pass the data from the background thread to the main thread.  I can't remember where I read to use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` for executing the web call. I also don't know if I should be doing the actual parsing on the background thread along with the web call, or when and where I should be calling `input.close()` and `connect.disconnect()`.  Or maybe I'm just inflating the wrong thing somewhere...

All the handler/adapter examples I look at are the same as what I have, the only real difference seems to be messing around threading.

At this point I only want to see it display the list.

Main Activity(I have a mockup splashScreenActivity class that starts MainActivity using `runnable()` and `Handler().postDelayed()`)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

    if (currentFragment == null){
        val fragment = PodcastListFragment.newInstance()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit()
    }
}
```

I basically followed an example right out of the BigNerdRanch book, except they used a database and singleton repository to initially populate their RecyclerViewer.  At this point I just want to display the list its generating before moving on to build a Database/Repository/ViewModel/etc.

```
class PodcastListFragment : Fragment() {

private var podcastList : MutableList<Podcast> = mutableListOf()  //this is just for short term to see it work
private lateinit var podcastRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private var podcastAdapter: PodcastAdapter? = PodcastAdapter(podcastList)

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list, container, false)

    podcastRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.podcast_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
    podcastRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    podcastRecyclerView.adapter = podcastAdapter

    updateUI(podcastList)

    return view
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    doInBackground()  //not actually sure where this should be called
}

private fun doInBackground() {

    val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    executor.execute {
        try {

            var podcast = Podcast()

            val url = URL(RSS)
            val connect: HttpURLConnection =
                url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection 

            connect.readTimeout = 10000
            connect.connectTimeout = 15000
            connect.requestMethod = "GET"

            connect.connect()
            val input: InputStream = connect.inputStream

            val factory: XmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
            factory.isNamespaceAware = true
            val parser: XmlPullParser = factory.newPullParser()

            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false)
            parser.setInput(input, null)

            var tagname: String?
            var text = ""

            var event = parser.eventType

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                tagname = parser.name

                when (event) {
                    XmlPullParser.START_TAG -> if (tagname == "item") podcast = Podcast()
                    XmlPullParser.TEXT -> text = parser.text
                    XmlPullParser.END_TAG -> when(tagname){
                        "title" -> podcast.title = text 
                        "itunes:author" -> podcast.author = text
                        "pubDate" -> podcast.date = text 
                        "guid" ->  podcast.id = parseGuid(text) 
                        "itunes:summary" -> podcast.reference = text 
                        "item" -> podcastList.add(podcast)
                    }
                }
                event = parser.next()
            }
            input.close() 
            connect.disconnect()
            for (obj in podcastList) {Log.d(TAG, "guid: ${obj.id} :: Title: ${obj.title}")}
        }
        catch (e: Exception) { e.printStackTrace() }
        catch (e: XmlPullParserException) { e.printStackTrace() }
        catch (e: NullPointerException) { e.printStackTrace() }
    }
}

// Log statements show the list is getting updated
private fun updateUI(podcasts: MutableList<Podcast>){
    podcastAdapter = PodcastAdapter(podcasts)
    podcastRecyclerView.adapter = podcastAdapter
}

private fun parseGuid(url: String) :String {

    val equalsign = url.indexOf("=", 0, false)
    return if ( equalsign != -1)
        url.slice(IntRange(equalsign+1, url.length-1))
    else ""
}

companion object{
    fun newInstance(): PodcastListFragment{
        return PodcastListFragment()
    }
}


/**********************************************************************************************
 *
 * PodcastHolder
 *
 * *******************************************************************************************/
private inner class PodcastHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    private val podcastTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.podcast_title)
    private val podcastDate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.podcast_date)
    private val podcastScripture: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.scripture_ref)

    private val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM d", Locale.getDefault()) //just use a string?


    fun bind(podcast: Podcast) {

        podcastTitle.text = podcast.title
        podcastDate.text = podcast.date
        podcastScripture.text = podcast.reference
    }

}

/**********************************************************************************************
 *
 * PodcastAdapter
 *
 * *******************************************************************************************/
private inner class PodcastAdapter(var podcasts: MutableList<Podcast>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PodcastHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PodcastHolder {

        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list_item, parent, false)
        return PodcastHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PodcastHolder, position: Int) {
        val podcast = podcasts[position]
        holder.bind(podcast)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = podcasts.size
}
```

I don't get any errors, just an empty RecyclerView, and a headache trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After playing around with `Thread.currentThread().name` I was able to figure out it was a threading problem even though I wasn't seeing an exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Call `doInBackground()` inside `onCreateView()`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list, container, false)

    podcastRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.podcast_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
    podcastRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    podcastRecyclerView.adapter = podcastAdapter

    doInBackground(); /// <<<<<<< change here

    updateUI(podcastList)

    return view
}
```

And add `notifyDataSetChanged()` after the background work is over in `doInBackground()`

```
private fun doInBackground() {

    val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    executor.execute {
        try {

            ///   ....  omitted code
            input.close() 
            connect.disconnect()
            for (obj in podcastList) {Log.d(TAG, "guid: ${obj.id} :: Title: ${obj.title}")}

            podcastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  // <<<< change here
        
/// ............ ....  omitted code
}
```

Comment: I'll keep this in mind.  Ultimately, I'd like to have the background call taking place "behind" the splash screen.  As it is right now I have a mock up splash screen show for 3seconds before MainActivity starts, which kicks off the actual call.  Illogical, I know, but I wanted to play around with having a splash screen.